# Distinction with phrases/usage

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, american-english

*The sun overhead and the sky clear*, Carl stepped into his future.

What is the difference between this absolute phrase and introductory phrases like in these other two examples?

1. Trying to be kind, I held the door open for the customer.
2. Beautiful and confident, the girl applied to the beauty pageant.

Comment: "The sun overhead and the sky clear" seems to have metaphorical meaning. But, for example, "trying to be kind" is literal in the given sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute phrases are noun phrases with their own modifiers.  There are no nouns in the other two introductory phrases.

“Trying to be kind” is a participial phrase.  “Beautiful and confident” is a coordination of adjectives.  Either of these structures can play an adjectival role.  Either of these examples can be understood as a modifier of the subject of its clause.  An absolute phrase cannot play that role.

I am the one trying to be kind.  The girl is someone both beautiful and confident.  Carl isn’t modified by an overhead sun or a clear sky.